# Is delete_all will ignore conditions which are based on joins table?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have been observed ActiveRecord **delete_all** is ignoring the joins table condition. Is this known issue from rails community?

Query:

```
DesignPartCategory.joins(:category).where(category: {site_id: INDIA}, designpart_uuid: ['123C']).delete_all
```

Expected result:

DELETE FROM `designpart_category` WHERE `designpart_category`.`designpart_uuid` IN ('123C') AND `designpart_category`.`category_id` IN (INDIA);

Actual Result:

```
 DELETE FROM `designpart_category` WHERE `designpart_category`.`designpart_uuid` IN (SELECT designpart_uuid FROM (SELECT `designpart_category`.`designpart_uuid` FROM `designpart_category` INNER JOIN `category` ON `category`.`category_id` = `designpart_category`.`category_id` WHERE (category.site_id =INDIA AND designpart_category.designpart_uuid in ('123C'))) __active_record_temp);
```

Currently **delete_all** operation just ignoring/discards the joins table condition and executing the rest of the query.

I'm assuming it should not be the case, it should throw the exception instead of ignoring joins. Please let us know your thoughts/comments on it.

Answer (score 1):

Seems there is some typo in your syntax, checkout this -

```
DesignPartCategory.joins(:category).where("categories.site_id = ? AND categories.designpart_uuid IN (?)", 'INDIA', ['123C']).delete_all
```

Alternatively you can try this: -

```
DesignPartCategory.joins(:category).where(categories: {site_id: 'INDIA', designpart_uuid: (['123C'])}).delete_all
```

Note: - [Delete vs Destroy](https://medium.com/@wkhearn/delete-vs-destroy-does-it-even-matter-8cb4db6aa660)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked following in your query?

```
 DELETE FROM `designpart_category` 
  WHERE `designpart_category`.`designpart_uuid` IN (
    SELECT designpart_uuid FROM (
      SELECT `designpart_category`.`designpart_uuid` 
      FROM `designpart_category` INNER JOIN `category` 
      ON `category`.`category_id` = `designpart_category`.`category_id` 
      WHERE (category.site_id =INDIA AND designpart_category.designpart_uuid in ('123C')
    )
  ) __active_record_temp
);
```

It filters as per your join query, check query fired in `IN`

Answer (score 0):

`delete_all` Deletes the records matching conditions without instantiating the records first, and hence not calling the destroy method nor invoking callbacks. So it will not take anything into account like `join`, `includes` etc...
[Check the documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/delete_all)

Comment: hope It should not be the case, it should throw the exception instead of ignoring joins.

Comment: It won't throw exception unless you define strong foreign key references.